# Enviar dois parâmetros em um hred usando asp classico

Tags: html, asp

Gostaria que o codigo abaixo enviasse dois parâmetros para a pagina request de nome `DetalheComercio.asp`. Os parametros seriam: Bairro e Categoria (o link abaixo envia apenas um parametro categoria). Essa pagina puxa os dados de uma Tabela de nome: TabBairro com o seguintes campos: IdBairro, Bairro, Estado, Detalhe, QuantFoto, Video, obs...

Essa pagina puxa os dados de uma tabela access de nome `TabCategoria`, com os seguintes campos: IdCategoria, Categoria, Obs..., e cria uma lista com link que dispara para a pagina `DetalheComercio.asp`. Ou seja, meu objetivo é fazer com que, ao ser clicado, o link abra a Pagina `Detalhecomercio.asp` e mostre todos os estabelecimentos com a categoria clicada no bairro presente. A pagina pode ser vista [neste link](http://dicabairro.t60.com.br/DetalheBairro.asp?Bairro=Posse).

Como se ve na pagina, eu queria que, ao clicar na categoria *Festa*, abrisse a pagina `DetalheComercio.asp` com todas a lojas da categoria *AUTOMOTIVO* (por exemplo) do bairro e assim tambem com os links de cada categoria.

O que ta acontecendo é que o link abre todos os registros sem se importar com o bairro.

Obs: Estou usando a pagina de cima dentro de outra pagina na forma de INCLUDE, portanto os links que se ver na pagina DetalheBairro.asp mostra a janela com esse include.

PAGINA QUE ENVIA O LINK

```
<!--#Include file="dbConexao.inc"-->

<%
'DIM conexaoDataBase
'DIM sqlLanc, rsDados
'Call abreConexao

sqlLanc= " SELECT * "
sqlLanc= sqlLanc & "FROM TabCategoria "
set rsDados = conexaoDataBase.Execute (sqlLanc)

%>


 <% do While not rsDados.eof %>
 <style type="text/css">
 a:link {
    color: #006;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
 </style>

<a href="DetalheComercio.asp?categoria=<% =rsDados("Categoria") %>"><% =Rsdados("categoria")%></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

<%rsDados.MoveNext
loop
%>
                      <%
rsDados.close
call fechaConexao
Set rsDados = Nothing
%>
```

SQL DA PAGINA QUE RECEBE O LINK

```
<%
DIM conexaoDataBase
DIM SqlLanc, rsDados, TotalBairro
Call abreConexao

sqlLanc= "SELECT TabLoja.categoria, TabLoja.Idloja, TabLoja.Empresa, TabLoja.rua, TabLoja.numero, TabLoja.Detalhe, TabLoja.telefone, TabBairro.IdBairro, TabBairro.bairro, TabBairro.cidade, TabBairro.estado,  TabBairro.quantfoto " 
sqlLanc = sqlLanc & "FROM TabBairro "
sqlLanc = sqlLanc & "INNER JOIN TabLoja "
sqlLanc = sqlLanc & "ON TabLoja.IdBairro = TabBairro.IdBairro "
sqlLanc = sqlLanc & "WHERE TabBairro.Bairro = '" +request.QueryString("Bairro") + "'"
'sqlLanc = sqlLanc & "WHERE TabCategoria.Categoria = '" +request.QueryString("Categoria") + "'"
SqlLanc =SqlLanc + "ORDER BY Tabbairro.bairro "
set rsDados = conexaoDataBase.Execute (SqlLanc)

TotalBairro = rsDados.recordcount
%>
```

Comment: A pagina ainda nao está terminada ESQUECI DE DIZER PARA CLICAR NO LINK (automotivo) para acesso a pagina DetalheComercio.asp. Obrigado

Comment: Cara vou lhe ser sincero, o texto está muito repetitivo, eu quase não consegui edita-lo. Uma dica, tente ser mais objetivo no problema e na dúvida, facilita bastante entender a pergunta e obter respostas.

Comment: Respondi pelo que consegui entender, mas como o @diegofm disse, tá difícil.

Answer (score 1):

No seu link, você está acessando o `recordset` de duas maneiras distintas: `rsDados` e `Rsdados`, além disso, no teu link está faltando a concatenação `&` da `querystring`, altere ele para:

```
<a href="DetalheComercio.asp?categoria=<%=Server.URLEncode(rsDados("categoria"))%>&bairro=<%=Server.URLEncode(rsDados("bairro"))%>"><%=rsDados("categoria")%></a>
```

Comment: Bem lembrado, @Bacco. Adicionei o [URLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525738(v=vs.90).aspx)